# Where should the singletons be created? and how can I instantiate an instance of them?

Tags: php, laravel, singleton, instance

I'm using laravel 4 to write my php application, and it contains only one view and one controller, I'm trying to create a singleton that would act as a very simple (sort of) database for a the short period of time during the use of the application, I don't need to save data for after the refresh of page.

this is the syntax I'm using in my main method in the controller:

```
App::singleton('myArray', function() {
        return new myData;
    });
```

(Do I need to have a separate model for my singelton?)
But how do I make an instance of it?
this is what I used in a different method on the same controller:

```
App::make('myData');
$myData = array_push($myData,$num);
```

My purpose is to let the user insert numbers (one by one by clicking a submit button) and insert those numbers to my singleton and in the end when a another button is clicked to display all the numbers stored in myData.

I know it sounds simple, but I'm just beginning to learn how to use the framework, a help would be appreciated.

Comment: Singleton !== persistent

Comment: I want myData to be created only one time, I don't want it to be particularly persistent

Comment: But if you're feeding the numbers to back-end PHP one at a time, you need to store them somewhere persistent (even if only in session) so that they're all still there when you click your other button

Comment: So I understand that I can't do that without a database? is there a way to save the number temporarily in the client?

Comment: You can store a number server side without a database, I already mentioned session; and yes, it would be easier storing all these numbers in the client browser, and sending them all as part of one request when the user finally clicks the other button

Comment: How do I store them in the client using PHP?

Comment: You can't store them in the client using PHP, you can only store them in the client using something that runs in the client, like javascript

Comment: You can write data to cookies.